# Найти элемент, заменить буквы, ввести в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Порядок действий такой
1. Ищем на странице input с определённым id
Вроде так

```
if ($('#input-id').find) {  
// тут код  
}
```

2. Если input на станице имеется, то ищем в "хлебных крошках" второе звено.
Верстка "хлебных крошек такая"

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <span>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Главная</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="separator"> » </span>
    <span>
        <a href="#" itemprop="item">
            <span>Категория</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="separator"> » </span>
    <span>
        <a href="#">
            <span>СубКатегория</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="separator"> » </span>
    <span class="title">Материал</span>
</div>
```

Требуемый пункт - "Категория". Отмечу, что вложенность "хлебных крошек" может быть разной, но расположение второго пункта всегда одно и то же.

Смог найти как-то так:

```
var first = $('.breadcrumbs span:nth-child(3) span').text();
```

3. Теперь надо взять последние две буквы и заменить их на букву "у".
   Надо было так?

   var second = maks.replace('ия', 'у');
4. Результат ввести в input c ID **input-id**
   Вот тут уже не знаю как правильно, мой вариант вообще не сработал

   $('#input-id').val = maks

Почти на 100% уверен, что даже те шаги, что смог сделать, выполнены плохо. Поправьте, пожалуйста, и покажите последний пункт.
Ещё был бы благодарен за вариант на чистом js, так как не хочется по пустякам дергать jQuery.

Comment: `maks.replace('ия', 'у')` тут не подойдет потому как может заменить искомую фразу как только ее найдет. И не факт что она будет именно в конце.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
if ($('#input-id').length > 0) {
  $('#input-id').val(maks); 
}
```

Но проверка не нужна. Пишите просто:

```
$('#input-id').val(maks);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var elem = $('#input-id');
  if (elem.length) {
    var text = $('.breadcrumbs span:nth-child(3) span').text();
    text = text.slice(0, -2) + 'у';
    elem.val(text);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <span>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Главная</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="separator"> » </span>
    <span>
        <a href="#" itemprop="item">
            <span>Категория</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="separator"> » </span>
    <span>
        <a href="#">
            <span>СубКатегория</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="separator"> » </span>
    <span class="title">Материал</span>
</div>

<input type="text" id="input-id">
```

Comment: Спасибо. Скажите насколько оптимален поиск элемента таким образом: `.breadcrumbs span:nth-child(3) span` . Может надо как-то другим образом, например считать порядковый номер span'а? пробовал eq(), но не вышло. И ещё, можно ли это на чистом js переписать? Вообще я изначально тоже так сделал ` slice(0, -2) + 'у' `, но потом подумал, что лучше в один заход как-то...

Comment: @Aaron, Метод вполне актуален и если структура крошек не будет изменяться, то работать будет как надо (доставать текст из второго пункта). Можно изначально задать второму пункту класс и уже от этого отталкиваться. Если для вас критична скорость - можно переписать на чистом js, работать будет быстрее.